# MS Excel. Returning items that matched

Tags: excel

I have two tables: first one is the table of animals with corresponding 4-column of let say, their individual features. The second one is the table of just one row where the snake resides and has recently taken "test" to determine what features still match with the test taken, which shall be presented in the Result column of the second table.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwKRM.png)
[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the VLOOKUP() function? Tell us why it can't do this job.

Answer (score 0):

put this formula in cell `E9` :

`=IF(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(A9;A2:A6;0)+ROW(A1) & ":E" & MATCH(A9;A2:A6;0)+ROW(A1));B9)>0;B9 & ", "; "") &  IF(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(A9;A2:A6;0)+ROW(A1) & ":E" & MATCH(A9;A2:A6;0)+ROW(A1));C9)>0;C9 & ", ";"")  & IF(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH(A9;A2:A6;0)+ROW(A1) & ":E" & MATCH(A9;A2:A6;0)+ROW(A1));D9)>0;D9;"")`

[image]

Or you can insert a helpmark cell like `F9` (match_row_index) and write the formula shorter , for doing that you should set this formula in `F9` : 
`=MATCH(A9;A2:A6;0)+ROW(A1)` and write this formula in `E9`:
`=IF(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("B" & F9 & ":E" & F9);B9)>0;B9 & ", "; "") &  IF(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("B" & F9 & ":E" & F9);C9)>0;C9 & ", ";"")  & IF(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("B" & F9 & ":E" & F9);D9)>0;D9;"")`

[image]